# How can I reflect hierarchy in output of Azure Resource Graph kusto query?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to create an Azure Monitor workbook that contains a dropdown parameter that allows you to select a subscription. I know of the existance of the "subscription picker"
parameter type but I want to include the names of the management group the subscription belongs to.

So, I have this:

```sql
resourcecontainers
| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
| extend mgs = properties.managementGroupAncestorsChain
| project name, mgs
```

which leds to this output:

| name | mgs |
| --- | --- |
| Sub1 | [{"displayName": "Test and Prod Development Group","name": "testprod" }, {"displayName": "Root Group","name": "b266655a-542b-4ab8-8d8f-6ce387638820"}] |
| Sub2 | [{"displayName":"Sandbox","name":"sandbox"},{"displayName":"Root Group","name":"266655a-542b-4ab8-8d8f-6ce387638820"}] |

Now, since I cannot build a tree like parameter I want to reflect the hierarchy like this:

| name | parent |
| --- | --- |
| Sub1 | Root Group -> Test and Prod Development Group |
| Sub2 | Root Group -> Sandbox |

I've tried to apply the `mv-apply` operator but after numerous attempts full of parser errors I found out that that operator is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/query-language#supported-kql-language-elements) for Azure Resource Graph queries.

What are my options, which operator could help me?

Comment: you can use `mv-expand` to achieve it. I understand that you want the subname as column1 and managementgroupancestorchain display values as another colum2. if yes you can use the below query 

`resourcecontainers
| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
| extend mgs = properties.managementGroupAncestorsChain
|mv-expand mgs
|project name, mgs.displayName,mgs
| summarize  mgs_dis= make_list(mgs_displayName) by name`

Comment: @VenkateshDodda  Ah yes, this is perfect. By adding `strcat_array` I get the desired result. If you post it as an answer I will accept it. Too bad `array_reverse` doesn't seem to be supported either so I can't really project from top to bottom but well, that I can live with.

Comment: I have posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mv-expand to achieve it. I understand that you want the subname as column1 and managementgroupancestorchain display values as another colum2. if yes you can use the below query

```
resourcecontainers 
| where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions" 
| extend mgs = properties.managementGroupAncestorsChain 
| mv-expand mgs 
| project name, mgs.displayName,mgs 
| summarize  mgs_dis= make_list(mgs_displayName) by name
```